# how to install nginx module on windows system (nginx)

Tags: windows, nginx

I want to install nginx-echo-module ; after I searched online ,I cant find anyway to do it ,can anyone help me ?
system : windows 7 
nginx  : nginx/1.6.2

Comment: You can find it here : https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/31-how-to-install-nginx-echomodule-latest-version.html

Comment: @pissall , I cant find anything about windows-nginx-echo-install in your site  , is anything else ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from :

[Is possible to install nginx with push module on windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/173882/is-possible-to-install-nginx-with-push-module-on-windows) as same goes with nginx echo module.

"""Short answer: No.

The Windows code is not open source and Nginx cannot link modules dynamically, as such you're limited to the binaries offered on nginx.org and the modules they include.

On a related note, Nginx on Windows is really sub-optimal and not very fast, you do not want to run it for anything other than development environment."""

Comment: Got it , thanks very much .It's a pity that my computer's system is windows in company

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  you can read more here

http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html

also
https://amefs.net/en/archives/1935.html